# How to make a function that can parse space sensitive strings in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string **str** defined as :

```
const str = `
 @get body {
     Anything here.....
     Any no. of lines

     Or, empty lines as above
 }
`
```

I made a function **get()** which, by name gets the element, the **@get** is marking , and yes the content between the **{** & **}**. It can be used something like this :

```
console.log(get(str))
// body
/*  
     Anything here.....
     Any no. of lines

     Or, empty lines as above
*/
```

So, the source of my function ( I don't have much experience to use **match()**, so I usually use **replace()** for getting the value as well as replacing with anything if and only if I require, so please feel free to edit my code ) :

```
const get = (val) => {
  val.replace(/@get(.*?)\{([\S\s]*?)\}/gm, (_, a, b) => {
    console.log(a)
    console.log(b)
   }
}
```

So, now my question is what if I remove the brackets i.e **{** & **}** ? Assumed syntax :

```
const str = `
 @get body 
    Anything here.....
    Any no. of lines

    Or, empty lines as above
 Don't catch me !
`
console.log(get(str))
```

Now, the output remains same. How how can I make my **get()** function space sensitive. You can see that the sentence *"Don't catch me !"*, have the same no. of spaces in front of it as of the **@get**, therefore it is parsed as an external content and is not stated as the content of the **@get body** block, hence not displayed. So, I am thinking how to do it ? Is it possible in javascript ?

Comment: Are you building a python interpreter?

Comment: Yeh, it looks alike python, syntax but the answer is no ! I am trying to figure out how simple a syntax can be made in javascript.

Comment: Why not just read line by line with a bit more code and less regex?

Comment: Please add an example

Comment: I have an idea. We can find the no. of spaces between the initial position of a line and the first word i.e @get here, and go on matching it until the same value is found. Afterwards the line with disimilar space counts will be wrapped into { and }, and then it can be easily understood by get(). Is this a good one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could do it with a regex. I would add additional logic to remove the leading spaces from the found content:

```js
const str = `
 @get body
    Anything here.....
    Any no. of lines

    Or, empty lines as above
 Don't catch me !
`;

function get(str) {
    let [,,name, content] = (str.match(/^([ ]*)@get\s*(.*\S).*((?:[\r\n]+^\1[ ].*)*)/m) || []);
    content = content.trim().replace(/^[ ]+/gm, ""); // remove leading spaces from all lines
    return [name, content];
}

console.log(get(str));
```

This requires that the content will consist of lines that have at least one more leading space than the `@get` line (or are empty).

Answer (score 0):

A bit too late on the scene.
But here's a similar function that uses match.

```js
 const str = `
 @get body 
    Anything here.....
    Any no. of lines

    Or, empty lines as above
 Do not catch me
 `
 
 const get = (str) => {
     let arr = str.match(/@get\s+(\S+)\s*[\r\n]+(\s+)(.*[\r\n]+(?:\2.*[\r\n]+|\s*[\r\n]+)*)/);
     let res = { 
       title: arr[1], 
       indentation: arr[2],
       content: arr[3]
     };   
    console.log(res.title, res.content);
 };
 
get(str);
```